# Blender 2.80 object won't show in render (.blend attached)

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I'm using Blender 2.80. Object shows in outliner and in viewport, but won't show when I render. I've been struggling for over a week now, what am I doing wrong?

Here is [the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ie6zesRCRQrugpv1GqMLTr2XAJPerxSu), the problematic object is called "WHYWONTRENDER".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your object has been flagged not to render
[image: set to not render]

Use the Filter drop down to show the options

[image: set filter to render]

Now enable Render on your object.

[image: render enabled]

This is catching a lot of people out in 2.8.

Comment: also, you can see that the object won't show in renders by going in the _Properties Window > Object Tab > Visibility_

Comment: OMG rob thanks, I cannot thank you enough.Somehow I dont see those 3 icons, just the "eye" one